# Setting description-labels in ios-pieChart

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, pie-chart, ios-charts

I'm working with [this](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts) library. I need to construct a PieChart do display some data. I copied and example peace of code from raywenderlich-website, so the question is that how can I **set** all labels from array "**months**" to below description labels (where now just "**qwe**" is shown) with the same colors as peaces OR how to **remove** them all?

[image]

Also it's impossible to change label "**description**" from right-below corner because it says me that "**description is immutable**"

```
@IBOutlet weak var pieChartView: PieChartView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let months = ["qwe", "asd", "zxc"]
        let unitsSold = [20.0, 15.0, 17.0]

        pieChartView.noDataTextDescription = "nothing here"

        setChart(months, values: unitsSold)

    }

    func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

        var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }

        let pieChartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries)

        let pieChartData = PieChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: pieChartDataSet)
        pieChartDataSet.label = ""
        pieChartView.data = pieChartData

        var colors: [UIColor] = []

         colors.append(UIColor.greenColor())
         colors.append(UIColor.blueColor())
         colors.append(UIColor.blackColor())

        pieChartDataSet.colors = colors





    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the library document, it says

> By default, all chart types support legends and will automatically generate and draw a legend after setting data for the chart.

**Edited**

READ through the library please!

As shown in the demo of the library, you should be able to do

```
pieChartView.descriptionText = "";
```

For the legend, you should be able to set the legend by

```
let legend = pieCharView.legend
legend.setCustom(colors: [UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.blackColor()], labels: ["qwe", "asd", "zxc"])
```

or disable it by

```
legend.isEnabled = false
```

Comment: I'm sure it is. But if as you said its one label's color is not one of pieces colors

Comment: Does the demo in the library showing the same effect? I'd rather trust the author rather than raywenderlich

Comment: demo is written in ObjC for my sadness

Comment: Can you post the tutorial link you followed? And also a storyboard screenshot if available.

Comment: link is on the 5th word

Comment: raywenderlich one please

Comment: I lied about him, my mistake. It was appCoda: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/